# Reading specific part of a File Content

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

How to read a string in another string where between `Starting Index` and first-encountered `Ending Index`

I have one giant file which contains info for each customers and they seperated the customers info with Starting and Ending Indexes and I need to get a specific customer info to display.

```
    Dim oFile As New FileInfo(sFileName)
    Dim sFileContent As String = oFile.OpenText().ReadToEnd()
    Dim iStartIndex As Integer = sFileContent.IndexOf(roNotification.StartByte)
    Dim iEndIndex As Integer = sFileContent.IndexOf(roNotification.EndByte, iStartIndex)
    Dim sCustomerInfo As String = sFileContent.Substring(iStartIndex + roNotification.StartByte.Length - 1, iEndIndex)
```

Nothing much tho. But it reads the file and put that giant file into `sFileContent` variable. I am not sure how efficient this way is (seems worse than MemoryStream).

Index strings can be more than 1 character.

**Edit:**

More info about the file, the file contains only one giant line and that lines contains all the info. I cannot touch on that file except for reading it since it has really confidential data.

I am looking for the string between Starting Index and First-encountered Ending Index exclusively.

Comment: You say it's a "giant" file - how big? How important is performance here? Is it really the string "Starting Index" you're looking for? Is the file broken into lines or anything else helpful?

Comment: Please refer to the my edit, @Jon Skeet. Thanks

Comment: A [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx#Y2639) might be an option to consider, especially if you have a pretty good idea where in the file you will be looking for data.

Comment: `Starting Index` and `Ending Index` are strings?  If so, please edit the question to make that more clear (around where you define those values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the file line-by-line:

```
Using reader = file.OpenText()
    Dim line As String
    While True
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If ReferenceEquals(Line, Nothing) Then Exit While

        'Parse the line and figure out what to do with it
    End While
End Using
```

This way, you'll never have more than one line in memory at a time.

Comment: It is just one line, one giant line which contains everything.

Comment: Then it completely depends on what the file looks like.

Answer (score 1):

DONT READ THE WHOLE LINE

Create a Binary / Text reader and call the read method with the start and end index. If the file is huge then optimise with a binary reader or something like that.

From -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            //This is an arbitrary size for this example.
            char[] c = null;

            while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
            {
                c = new char[5];
                sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
                //The output will look odd, because
                //only five characters are read at a time.
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but my case is really too complicated for such a solution like yours. I wish it could be more explanatory, that's why I asked one simple question and will handle the rest of it.